# NetworkInterface.isUp() returns false

Tags: android, network-interface

I've the problem that on one of my Android test tablets (running Android 4.4.2) has `NetworkInterface.isUp()` returning `false`. Also, `NetworkInterface.getInetAddresses()` returns an empty `Enumeration<InetAddress>`. Strangely, I *have* access to the Internet and when I look at the Wifi network details, the device has obtained an IP address.

On another device (running Android 4.2.2) are no problems reported.

So these are my two questions:

1. What exactly is an interface being up? The docs are very brief about it.

   > Returns true if this network interface is up.

   I mean, what's up? — literally.
2. What's (the cause of) the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the right `NetworkInterface` instance? There may be more than one.

Comment: Did you add your manifest ```android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE ``` permission ?

Comment: Yep! I have added all internet and network related permissions, to make sure that is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface being "up" is the fact that a network interface has an open connection. Common interfaces being "up" are as follows:

- Interface **lo** (being **localhost**, **127.0.0.1** or **::1**).
- The currently active network interface. For example, **wlan0** if wifi is active.

How it works is as follows. You might have multiple network interfaces being up. All networking interfaces are accessible through `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`. Each of those network interfaces are bound to one or more addresses (for example, your primary wifi device, commonly named **wlan0**, can have both an IPv4 as an IPv6 address). Those addresses are accessible through

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nis = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
NetworkInterface ni = nis.nextElement();
Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = ni.getInetAddresses();
```

You should check whether you are accidentally referring to the localhost, which is (almost) always up, or another interface which is up.